# material ui lab date picker, Can't resolve '@material-ui/lab/AdapterDateFns'

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, material-ui

Can't resolve '@material-ui/lab/AdapterDateFns'

Can't resolve '@material-ui/lab/DateTimePicker'

Can't resolve '@material-ui/lab/LocalizationProvider'

I am getting these errors even after having installed @material-ui/lab

Comment: Do `npm install @material-ui/lab`

Comment: I have the same problem. even after hitting 'npm install @material-ui/lab' and 'npm install @mui/lab' the problem still exists. anyone willing to help?

Answer (score 16):

This works for me very well

```
npm install @mui/lab
```

In Material UI v5 you need to install @mui/lab.My dependencies are here :

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.54",
    "@mui/material": "^5.2.1",
  }
```

For more information check this [link](https://mui.com/material-ui/about-the-lab/)

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Comment: What is exact requirement? I have `"@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.73", "@mui/material": "^5.4.4", "date-fns": "^2.28.0"` in my `package.json`, still I get this error.

Answer (score 12):

I have a working codesandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-wave-8xjy4

Make sure both `@material-ui/core` and `@material-ui/lab` are at version `"5.0.0-alpha.24"` or above as I ran into the same import errors as you when following the guide at: https://next.material-ui.com/guides/pickers-migration/

```
// package.json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "11.1.5",
    "@emotion/styled": "11.1.5",
    "@material-ui/core": "5.0.0-alpha.24",
    "@material-ui/lab": "5.0.0-alpha.24",
    "date-fns": "2.17.0",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.0"
  },
}
```

Comment: What is exact requirement? I have `"@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.73", "@mui/material": "^5.4.4", "date-fns": "^2.28.0"` in my `package.json`, still I get this error.

Answer (score 6):

Try running `npm install @material-ui/core@next` and `npm install @material-ui/lab@next`

This should move you to version 5.

If the need arises, delete the `node_modules` folder and run `npm install`.

Now if you look into the `lab` folder in node_modules/@material-ui, you will see the

Answer (score 2):

For date pickers in React MUI install the below two:

- @mui/x-date-pickers for the free community version.
- The date library to manipulate the date.

```
npm install @mui/x-date-pickers
    
// Install date library (if not already installed)
npm install dayjs
```

For rendering the date picker:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { AdapterDayjs } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs';
import { LocalizationProvider } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider';
import { DatePicker } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/DatePicker';

export default function FirstComponent() {
  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
      <DatePicker />
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
}
```

For more details, read this [link](https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/getting-started/).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you installed a date management library. I think that `@material-ui/lab/AdapterDateFns` will be supported with the date-fns library.

[date-fns installation](https://date-fns.org/docs/Getting-Started#installation)

I read it at [mui documentation for React Date Picker](https://mui.com/components/date-picker/).

Answer (score 0):

THIS WORKED FOR ME!!!!
I went into the node_modules to look for the specific files:

1. The location of the imports was not accurate so I changed them
   accordingly
2. Then all these components are exported as a default so I removed
   the curly braces and it worked for me.

**I have installed these :**

```
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.5",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.5",
    "@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.108",
    "@mui/material": "^5.10.14",
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying multiple mentioned solutions, below worked for me -

```
npm install @mui/x-date-pickers
```