# ReactJS Material UI how to use DatePicker, LocalizationProvider, AdapterDateFns

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, material-ui

I am trying to use the Material UI [date picker](https://next.material-ui.com/components/date-picker/#basic-usage) on my project. According to [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@material-ui/lab) the last version of @material-ui/lab is 4.0.0-alpha.57, which is the one I have installed:

[image]

however

```
import AdapterDateFns from '@material-ui/lab/AdapterDateFns';
import LocalizationProvider from '@material-ui/lab/LocalizationProvider';
import DatePicker from '@material-ui/lab/DatePicker';
```

complain

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@material-ui/lab/AdapterDateFns' 
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@material-ui/lab/DatePicker'
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@material-ui/lab/LocalizationProvider'
```

How can I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i had the same issue,

you have to upgrade both of your @material-ui/lab and @material-ui/core to 5.0.0-alpha.24 and above. This is already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/66125652

For me i tried this solution and upgraded to alpha versions but a lot of things that i've already built with @material-ui/core 4.11.3 got screwed. So i went back to 4.11.3.

Comment: Of course, no problem, i found an alternative which you can use Material-ui Picker without upgrading to Alpha, Here's the doc Check This out : https://material-ui-pickers.dev/getting-started/installation.

If my comment helped you in any way i would be glad to have your help with a vote (smile)